# ¿Diferencia entre dos arrays php?

Tags: php, array

Tengo dos arrays: `A1` y `B1`.

¿Cómo hago para compararlos y hallar aquellos registros del primer array que tienen alguna diferencia respecto al segundo?

```
$a1 = Array
    (
    "0" => Array
        (
        "Empresa" => "HHH",
        "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
        "ID" => "M2",
        "Valor" => "200",
        "Nombre" => "BONI"
    ),
    "1" => Array
        (
        "Empresa" => "HHH",
        "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
        "ID" => "M1",
        "Valor" => "100",
        "Nombre" => "SUELDO"
    )
);

$b1 = Array
    (
    "0" => Array
        (
        "Empresa" => "HHH",
        "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
        "ID" => "M1",
        "Valor" => "100",
        "Nombre" => "SUELDO"
    ),
    "1" => Array
        (
        "Empresa" => "HHH",
        "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
        "ID" => "M2",
        "Valor" => "200",
        "Nombre" => "BONI"
    )
);
```

Comment: ¿El orden importa? En el ejemplo que pones $a1 y $b1 tienen los mismos elementos pero en distinto orden. También, supongo que dos registros se consideran el mismo si tienen el mismo ID, ¿o cómo?

Answer (score 3):

No se si ya probaste con array_diff, pero mas o menos esto te puede servir para experimentar:

```
<?PHP

$t = count($a1);

 for ($x=0;$x<$t; $x++){

     $resultado = array_diff($a1[$x], $b1[$x]);

     print_r($resultado);

 }

?>
```

Comment: @Edgar Conrado: Lo probe con el ejemplo y me funcionó, Retorna: `Array ( [ID] => M2 [Valor] => 200 [Nombre] => BONI ) Array ( [ID] => M1 [Valor] => 100 [Nombre] => SUELDO )` . Si estoy equivocado te ruego explicarme. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Como tienes un array asociativo array_diff_uassoc que  calcula la diferencia entre arrays con un chequeo adicional de índices que se realiza por una función de devolución de llamada suministrada por el usuario.
Dejo código de ejemplo

```
<?php
function key_compare_func($a, $b)
{
if ($a === $b) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;
}

$array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff_uassoc($array1, $array2, "key_compare_func");
print_r($result);
?>
```

//---------------------------- resultado
        Array
        (
           [b] => brown
           [c] => blue
           [0] => red
         )

Comment: Buen punto, pero solo funciona para arrays simples,

Comment: Es lo mismo solo que lo ajustas al arreglo complejo, te dejo in enlace con, un ejemplo
    http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b552435514d685f547dab400e4bc34d1e2145cd6

Comment: Aquí lo mejore un poco: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/97f8778e86fefcd4d1643d2f7b506c0a8e14987c

Answer (score 2):

Dado que estas usando un arreglo multidimensional, ocupas de una funcion recursiva para poder comparalos:

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
    {
        foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                if(!isset($array2[$key]))
                {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                }
                elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
                {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                }
                else
                {
                    $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if($new_diff != FALSE)
                    {
                        $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
            {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
    }

    $a1 = Array
        (
        "0" => Array
        (
            "Empresa" => "HHH",
            "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
            "ID" => "M2",
            "Valor" => "200",
            "Nombre" => "BONI"
        ),
        "1" => Array
        (
            "Empresa" => "HHH",
            "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
            "ID" => "M1",
            "Valor" => "100",
            "Nombre" => "SUELDO"
        )
    );
    $b1 = Array
        (
        "0" => Array
        (
            "Empresa" => "HHH",
            "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
            "ID" => "M1",
            "Valor" => "100",
            "Nombre" => "SUELDO"
        ),
        "1" => Array
        (
            "Empresa" => "HHH",
            "Paga" => "13/01/2015",
            "ID" => "M2",
            "Valor" => "200",
            "Nombre" => "BONI"
        )
    );

    print_r(array_diff_assoc_recursive($a1, $b1));
```

Comment: En esta solución se considera que el orden importa (OP no especificó sobre ello), no devuelve el registro completo sino sólo los campos que cambian, y falla si se han añadido nuevos campos en el segundo array